# Getting values from Qt widgets and using them for a buffer

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I am writing a simple plugin that finds buffer. My gui has 2 combo box and 1 Line edit. The first combo box will have a drop down of values  from column 'States' and 2nd combo will have a drop down of values from column 'Cities'. Note that the Cities will be filtered in the combo box depending on the states selected. And 3rd Lineedit gets a distance from the user. As a result, I want buffer for the cities (from the 2nd combo box) with the user specified 'distance value' given in the lineedit box.I tried QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer() function in QGIS API. But the first argument is a layer for the above mentioned function. Instead i want my gui to take value from the city combo and lineedit and find buffer. How to accomplish. Sorry for the lengthy post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```
# Get buffer distance and selected city 
dist = float( myLineEdit.text() )
city = myComboBo.currentText()

# Get the feature corresponding to the selected city
expr = QgsExpression('"Cities" = \'' + city + '\'' )
it = myLayer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
feature = it.next()

# Perform a buffer on the feature geometry
myBufferPolygon = feature.geometry().buffer(dist, 50)
```

Then you could use the `myBufferPolygon` to create a new feature and store it in another [vector layer](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html) or something like that.

Comment: Can you explain the what QgsExpression(' "Cities" = \ '' + city + '\ '') does exactly?

Comment: It's equivalent to something like `"Cities" = 'myCity'` but escapes the quotes properly. Since you need to get a feature in order to get its geometry and apply a buffer, you can get it by using a filter expression. `"Cities" = 'myCity'` is an expression that lets you get exactly the feature whose `Cities` value is the selected by the user. In summary, `QgsExpression('"Cities" = \'' + city + '\'' )` allows you to define a filter in order to get a feature by attribute.

Comment: Great Explanation gcarrillo. Will check and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou gcarrillo, the code works!

Comment: I tried the above code. It is now showing the error.                                                                 feature = it.next()                  stopIteration