# Getting number from QLineEdit and passing it to buffer function in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a plugin which finds buffer. In that i am using lineedit for getting distance from the user and pass it to the buffer function. My current code throws an error "'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'Value'. I had also attached my code for reference.

```
 def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Clear the QcomboBox before loading layers
    self.dlg.Statecombo.clear()
    self.dlg.Citycombo.clear()
    self.dlg.DistancelineEdit.clear()
    layers = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            idx = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex( 'name_1' )  #this field contains state names
            uv = layer.dataProvider().uniqueValues( idx )

            """Adding the state names to the combo box"""
            for i in uv:
                if i:
                    self.dlg.Statecombo.addItem(str(i))


            QObject.connect(self.dlg.Statecombo, SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), self.findTheCityNames)
            QObject.connect(self.dlg.Citycombo, SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"), self.calcDistance)

# Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    #if result:
    if result:
        distance = self.dlg.DistancelineEdit.value()
        new_distance = distance
        number = self.dlg.number_buf.value()
        QgsGeometry.buffer(new_distance , 2)            
        pass

def findTheCityNames(self):
    self.dlg.Citycombo.clear()
    ct = self.dlg.Statecombo.currentText()
    st = "name_1='"+ct+"'"
    exp = QgsExpression(st)
    fidAndVal = {}        
    #QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), "info", st) 

    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()

    iterFeat = layer.getFeatures()

    for f in iterFeat:
        val = exp.evaluate(f)
        if bool(val):
            attrs = f.attributes()
            idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')
            cityName = f.attributes()[idx]
            fidInt = f.id()
            fidAndVal[fidInt] = cityName

    for x in fidAndVal.keys():
        self.dlg.Citycombo.addItem(fidAndVal[x])


def calcDistance(self):
    pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the `text()` function, as stated in the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html). I would also parse it directly as a float, being a distance.

```
distance = float( self.dlg.DistancelineEdit.text() )
```

*Note: Actually, [I had already told you so](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134354/getting-values-from-attribute-table-as-well-as-from-user-and-finding-buffer/134375#134375).*

Comment: Thanx gcarrillo